# C++ undefined reference to namespace Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, reference, namespaces, undefined

I have an undefined reference issue with the following C++ scripts:

### Main.cpp

```
#include"C:/Users/Steve/Desktop/Project/MyProject_YoungTableau/include/header_A.hpp"
#include"C:/Users/Steve/Desktop/Project/MyProject_YoungTableau/include/header_B.hpp"
#include"C:/Users/Steve/Desktop/Project/MyProject_YoungTableau/include/header_C.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <limits.h>
#include <sstream> 
#include <stdbool.h>

using namespace ns_young_tableau_A;
using namespace ns_young_tableau_B;
using namespace ns_young_tableau_C;

///MAIN
int main() {

ns_young_tableau_C::YoungTableau_C YOUNG_TABLEAU;

///Tableau size
ns_young_tableau_A::YoungTableau_A::Tableau_T Tableau;
Tableau.m = 4;
Tableau.n = 4;
Tableau.elements = NULL;


//'Prova'
//'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'

ns_young_tableau_B::YoungTableau_B MCYT;
ns_young_tableau_A::YoungTableau_A::Cell_T CurrentYT; 

CurrentYT = MCYT.MakeCellYT(Tableau.m, Tableau.n);
//'------------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------------------------'

///Initialize elements in the tableau
int elements[Tableau.m * Tableau.n];

/// # of elements in the tableau
int ElementSize = sizeof(elements)/sizeof(*elements);

///Initialize tableau
Tableau = {Tableau.m, Tableau.n,elements};
cout << "Tableau!\n" << endl;


YOUNG_TABLEAU.InitEmptyTableauYT(Tableau);


///Insert elements in the tableau
YOUNG_TABLEAU.InsertYT(Tableau,9);
YOUNG_TABLEAU.InsertYT(Tableau,16);
YOUNG_TABLEAU.InsertYT(Tableau,3);
YOUNG_TABLEAU.InsertYT(Tableau,2);
YOUNG_TABLEAU.InsertYT(Tableau,4);
YOUNG_TABLEAU.InsertYT(Tableau,8);
YOUNG_TABLEAU.InsertYT(Tableau,5);
YOUNG_TABLEAU.InsertYT(Tableau,14);
YOUNG_TABLEAU.InsertYT(Tableau,12);

cout << "\nAfter insert:" << endl;

///Inserted elements
YOUNG_TABLEAU.TableauPrint(Tableau);

///Minimum element extracted from the tableau
cout << "\n Minimum element in the tableau: " <<YOUNG_TABLEAU.ExtractMinYT(Tableau) << endl;

///Square of a number calculating using a constexpr
int Value = YOUNG_TABLEAU.SquareConstExpr(Tableau.n);
///Square of a number calculating using template function
int Value2 = YOUNG_TABLEAU.SquareTemplate(Tableau.n);

//========== ?? Revise resulting indexes ?? ==========
///Find a specific element in a tableau
if(YOUNG_TABLEAU.FindYT(Tableau, Value))
    cout << "Value founded icn position (" << ns_young_tableau_i_C::c.i << 
"," << ns_young_tableau_i_C::c.j << ")" << endl;

int ArrayElements[16] = {9,16,3,2,4,8,5,14,12,1,17,13,6,9,15,26};

///Sorted elements in the tableau
YOUNG_TABLEAU.SortYT(ArrayElements,Tableau.m);

cout << "\nSorted Elements:\n" << endl;

///Print sorted elements in the tableau
for(int i = 0; i < Tableau.m * Tableau.m; i++){
    cout << " " <<  ns_young_tableau_i_C::Array2[i];
}

cout << "\n" << endl;

return 0;
}
```

---

### header_A.hpp

```
//Avoid multiple inclusions of a header file in a translation
//unit
#pragma once

#include <stddef.h>
//#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <istream>

#include <limits.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdbool.h>


/** @brief "Namespace YoungTableau"
* Contains functions and structures to make and manage a tableau
*/
namespace ns_young_tableau_A {


/**
 * @brief "YoungTableau_A"
 * @tparam T
 */
class YoungTableau_A {
public:

/**
     * @brief "Cell (i,j)"
     * @details  "Single cell in the tableau"
     *            i,j: cell indexes
     */
    struct Cell_T {
    //typedef struct Cell_T {

        int i;
        int j;

    } cell_YT,c,d,l,r,u,CurrentYT;

    /**
     * @brief "Tableau"
     * @details  "Young Tableau (table)",
     *      elements: elements in the tableau
     *      m: # of rows
     *      n: # of columns
     */
     struct Tableau_T{
    //typedef struct Tableau_T{

        int m;
        int n;
        int *elements;

    } Tableau,TableauSorted;



///Accepted movements 
///---------------------------------------------------------
/**
* @brief "Upward: Up"
* @details "Upward movement from the current cell"
     * @tparam  R
     * @param[in] c
     * @return position (i,j)
     */
    template<typename T>
    T UpYT(T c);

    /**
     * @brief   Downward: Down
     * @details "Downward movement from the current cell"
     * @tparam  R
     * @param[in] c
     * @return position (i,j)
     */
    template<typename T>
    T DownYT(T c);

    /**
     * @brief   Leftward: Left
     * @details "Leftward movement from the current cell"
     * @tparam  R
     * @param[in] c
     * @return position (i,j)
     */
    template<typename T>
    T LeftYT(T c);

    /**
     * @brief   Rightward: Right
     * @details "Rightward movement from the current cell"
     * @tparam  R
     * @param[in] c
     * @return position (i,j)
     */
    template<typename T>
    T RightYT(T c);

///---------------------------------------------------------
};

} // namespace young_tableau


//namespace YT = young_tableau;

#include "impl/header_A.i.hpp"
```

---

### header_A.i.hpp

```
namespace ns_young_tableau_i_A {

template<typename T>
T UpYT(T c){

    T Result = {c.i - 1, c.j};

    return Result;
}

template<typename T>
T DownYT(T c){

    T Result = {c.i + 1, c.j};

    return Result;
}

template<typename T>
T LeftYT(T c){

   T Result = {c.i, c.j - 1};

    return Result;
}

template<typename T>
T RightYT(T c){

    T Result = {c.i, c.j + 1};

    return Result;
}


} // namespace young_tableau
```

---

### header_B.hpp

```
//Avoid multiple inclusions of a header file in a translation
//unit
#pragma once

#include "C:/Users/Steve/Desktop/Project/MyProject_YoungTableau/include/header_A.hpp"
#include <cstddef>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream> 

//using namespace ns_young_tableau_A;

/** @brief Namespace brief
* Contains functions and structures to make and manage a tableau
*/
namespace ns_young_tableau_B{

/**
 * @brief "YoungTableau_B"
 * @details "Inhereted from A class"
 * @tparam T
 */

class YoungTableau_B {
public:

/// @brief Create an object with methods in YoungTableau_A class
//YoungTableau_A YOUNG_TABLEAU_A;

/**
* @brief "Make cell"
* @details Return the value in position (i,j) from the Young     Tableau 
* @tparam  R
* @param[in] i
* @param[in] j
* @return position (i,j)
*/
 template<typename T>
        ns_young_tableau_A::YoungTableau_A::Cell_T MakeCellYT(T i, T j);


        /**
         * @brief "Within Cell"
         * @details Check that current position is within the Young Tableau contour 
         * @tparam  R
         * @param[in] tableau
         * @param[in] c
         * @return 'yes' if the element c exists in the tableau
         *         'no' otherwise
         */
        template<typename R,typename T>
        bool WithinYT(R *Tableau, T c);

        /**
         * @brief "Get cell"
         * @details Find and return the value of the element 
         * in 'index' position (calculated from i,j indexes)
         * @tparam  R
         * @param[in] tableau
         * @param[in] c
         * @return corrispondent element in the tableau
         */
        template<typename R,typename T>
        int GetYT(R *Tableau, T c);

        /**
         * @brief "Set cell"
         * @details Set a value for the element in 'index' position  
         * @tparam  R
         * @param[in] tableau
         * @param[in] c
         * @param[in] value
         * @return void
         */
        template<typename R,typename T>
        void SetYT(R *Tableau, T c, int Value);
};


} // namespace young_tableau

//namespace YT = young_tableau;


#include "impl/header_B.i.hpp"
```

---

### header_B_i.hpp

```
//using namespace ns_young_tableau_A;

namespace ns_young_tableau_i_B {

template<typename T>
ns_young_tableau_A::YoungTableau_A::Cell_T MakeCellYT(T i, T j){

    T Result = {i,j};

    return Result;
}       


template<typename R,typename T>
bool WithinYT(R Tableau, T c){
    return (c.i >= 0 && c.j >= 0 && c.i < Tableau->m && c.j < Tableau->n);
}


template <typename R, typename T>
int GetYT(R Tableau, T c){

    auto IndexYT = c.i * Tableau->n + c.j;

    return Tableau->elements[IndexYT];
}


///Set a value for the element in 'index' position  
template<typename R, typename T>
void SetYT(R Tableau, T c, int Value){

    auto IndexYT = c.i * Tableau->n + c.j;

    Tableau->elements[IndexYT] = Value;
}
// namespace young_tableau
```

---

### header_C.hpp

```
//Avoid multiple inclusions of a header file in a translation
//unit
#pragma once
#include"C:/Users/Steve/Desktop/Project/MyProject_YoungTableau/include/header_A.hpp"
#include"C:/Users/Steve/Desktop/Project/MyProject_YoungTableau/include/header_C.hpp"

#include <cstddef>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream> 

//using namespace ns_young_tableau_A;
//using namespace ns_young_tableau_B;

/// @brief Namespace brief
/// Contains functions and structures to make and manage a tableau 
namespace ns_young_tableau_C {

/**
 * @brief "YoungTableau_C"
 * @details "Inhereted from A and B classes"
 * @tparam T
 */

class YoungTableau_C {
public:

    /**
     * @brief "Tableau print"
     * @details Print tableau on screen
     * @tparam  R
     * @param[in] tableau
     * @return void
     */
    template<typename R>
    void TableauPrint(R Tableau);

    /**
     * @brief "Init empty tableau"
     * @details Create a new empty tableau
     * @tparam  R
     * @param[in] tableau
     * @return correspondent element in the tableau
     */
    template<typename R>
    void InitEmptyTableauYT(R Tableau);

    /**
     * @brief "Extract tableau min value"
     * @details Extract the element with minimum value from the Young Tableau 
     * @tparam  R
     * @param[in] tableau
     * @return minimum value in the tableau
     */
    template<typename R>
    int ExtractMinYT(R Tableau);


    /**
     * @brief "Insert new element in the tableau"
     * @details Insert a new element in the Young Table 
     * @tparam  R
     * @param[in] tableau
     * @param[in] key
     * @return void
     */
    template<typename R>
    R InsertYT(R Tableau, int Key);


    /**
     * @brief "Sort elements of the tableau"
     * @details Sort elements in the Young Tableau
     * @tparam  R
     * @param[in] tableau elements
     * @param[in] size_sqrt
     * @return void
     */ 
    template<typename R, typename T>
    void SortYT(R Array, T SizeSqrt);


    /**
     * @brief "Find inside tableau"
     * @details Find an existing element in the Young Tableau 
     * @tparam  R
     * @param[in] tableau 
     * @param[in] key
     * @return 'yes' if element found
     *         'no' otherwise
     */ 
    template<typename R>
    int FindYT(R Tableau, int Key);

    /**
     * @brief Square (constant expression)
     * @details Constant expression (computed at compile-time)
     * @tparam R
     * @param[in] value
     * @return square of value
     */
    template<typename R>
    constexpr SquareConstExpr(R Value) {
        return Value * Value;
    }

        /**
     * @brief Square  (template function)
     * @details template function (computed at compile-time)
     * @tparam R
     * @param[in] value
     * @return square of value
     */
    template<typename R>
    R SquareTemplate(R a) {
        return a * a; 
    }
};

} 

//namespace YT = young_tableau;


#include "impl/header_C.i.hpp"
```

---

It seems that the compiler cannot find the correct references to the hpp files.
Actually I'm using Visual Studio Code editor.
I've added the path of the .hpp files (header_A,header_B,header_C) in c_cpp_properties.json as following...

---

```
"intelliSenseMode": "msvc-x64",
        "browse": {
            "path": [
                "${workspaceFolder}",
                "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/include/*","C:/Users/Steve/Desktop/Project/MyProject_YoungTableau/include/header_A.hpp","C:/Users/Steve/Desktop/Project/MyProject_YoungTableau/include/header_B.hpp","C:/Users/Steve/Desktop/Project/MyProject_YoungTableau/include/header_C.hpp","C:/Users/Steve/Desktop/Project/MyProject_YoungTableau/include/header_Source.hpp",
                "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include/c++/tr1",
                "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include/c++",
                "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include",
                "C:/MinGW/lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/include/c++/mingw32",

"C:/Users/Steve/Desktop/Project/MyProject_YoungTableau/src/Source.cpp*",
                "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/atlmfc/include/*",
                "C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/8.1/Include/um",
                "C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/8.1/Include/shared",
                "C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/8.1/Include/winrt"
            ],
            "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
            "databaseFilename": ""
```

---

.... and tried do compile using the following g++ command in tasks.json file:

### Tasks.json

```
{
// See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
// for the documentation about the tasks.json format
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "echo",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "g++",
        "args": ["-g","-Iinclude","C:/Users/Steve/Desktop/Project/MyProject_YoungTableau/src/Main.cpp","C:/Users/Steve/Desktop/Project/MyProject_YoungTableau/include/*.hpp","-o","Main"],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        }
    }
]
}
```

---

This is one of the possible errors that appears:

---

```
C:\Users\Steve\AppData\Local\Temp\ccIsSjRK.o: In function `main':
C:/Users/Steve/Desktop/Project/MyProject_YoungTableau/src/Main.cpp:68:     undefined reference to `ns_young_tableau_A::YoungTableau_A::Cell_T     ns_young_tableau_B::YoungTableau_B::MakeCellYT<int>(int, int)'
C:/Users/Steve/Desktop/Project/MyProject_YoungTableau/src/Main.cpp:82:     undefined reference to `void     ns_young_tableau_C::YoungTableau_C::InitEmptyTableauYT<ns_young_tableau_A::Young    Tableau_A::Tableau_T>(ns_young_tableau_A::YoungTableau_A::Tableau_T)'
C:/Users/Steve/Desktop/Project/MyProject_YoungTableau/src/Main.cpp:86:     undefined reference to `ns_young_tableau_A::YoungTableau_A::Tableau_T     ns_young_tableau_C::YoungTableau_C::InsertYT<ns_young_tableau_A::YoungTableau_A:    :Tableau_T>(ns_young_tableau_A::YoungTableau_A::Tableau_T, int)'
C:/Users/Steve/Desktop/Project/MyProject_YoungTableau/src/Main.cpp:87:     undefined reference to `ns_young_tableau_A::YoungTableau_A::Tableau_T     ns_young_tableau_C::YoungTableau_C::InsertYT<ns_young_tableau_A::YoungTableau_A:    :Tableau_T>(ns_young_tableau_A::YoungTableau_A::Tableau_T, int)'
C:/Users/Steve/Desktop/Project/MyProject_YoungTableau/src/Main.cpp:88:     undefined reference to `ns_young_tableau_A::YoungTableau_A::Tableau_T     ns_young_tableau_C::YoungTableau_C::InsertYT<ns_young_tableau_A::YoungTableau_A:    :Tableau_T>(ns_young_tableau_A::YoungTableau_A::Tableau_T, int)'
```

---

I cannot understand which the problem is.
Been slamming my head against this issue for a while.
I hope I was sufficiently clear :)

Thanks to everybody for your help :)

---

### ExtractMinYT

```
template<typename R>
    int YoungTableau_C::ExtractMinYT(R Tableau){

  //          CurYT = {0,0};
            //Next = {0,0};

            ns_young_tableau_A::YoungTableau_A::Cell_T CurYT2;
            //CurYT2 = MCYT.MakeCellYT(Tableau.m, Tableau.n);
            CurYT2 = {0,0};
            ns_young_tableau_A::YoungTableau_A::Cell_T Next2;
            //Next2 = MCYT.MakeCellYT(Tableau.m, Tableau.n);
            Next2 = {0,0}; 

            ///Minimum element found in the tableau
            int MinYT = 0; 

            ///The new minimum element found
            int NewOne = INT_MAX;

            /**Start with the current minimum fixed to an Infinitive value
               Polymorphism: 'get' from YoungTableau_C Class */
            MinYT = GYT.GetYT(Tableau,CurYT2);

            ///Polymorphism: 'set' inhereted from YoungTableau_B class
            SYT.SetYT(Tableau,CurYT2, INT_MAX);

            /**Find the minimum element in the tableau comparing the current element
               current_YT with the neighbours and exchange it with the smallest */
            while (true) {

                ///Minimum element actually found
                int SmallestYT;

                ///Move downward from the current position
                d = DYT.DownYT(CurYT2);

                ///Move rightward from the current position
                r = RYT.RightYT(CurYT2);


                /** If there is a smaller element moving downward from the current position,
                move downward the cursor and update the smallest with the new element found */
                if(WYT.WithinYT(Tableau,d) && GYT.GetYT(Tableau,d) < NewOne) {
                    Next2 = d;
                    SmallestYT = GYT.GetYT(Tableau,Next2);
                } else {
                    SmallestYT = NewOne;
                }


                /** If there is a smaller element moving rightward from the current position,
                   move rightward the cursor and update the smallest with the new element found */
                if(WYT.WithinYT(Tableau,r) && GYT.GetYT(Tableau,r) < SmallestYT) {
                    Next2 = r;
                    SmallestYT = GYT.GetYT(Tableau, Next2);
                }

                /** If the last element found is the smallest in the tableau,
                update the current position of the tableau with this element and return it */
                if(NewOne == SmallestYT){     
                    SYT.SetYT(Tableau,CurYT2,NewOne);
                    break;
                }

                SYT.SetYT(Tableau,CurYT2, SmallestYT);
                CurYT2 = Next2;
            }

            return MinYT;
        }
```

---

Comment: Would be helpful if you provided header_C.hpp too.

Comment: Thank you very much in advance for your partecipation ChrisD :) I added header_C.hpp. I haven't loaded header_C_i.hpp because is too long and it's very similar to header_B_i.hpp (if I solve the problem for header_B_i.hpp I also solve it for header_C.hpp and for header_C_i.hpp :) )

Answer (score 0):

For the first error there are a couple of issues. Your class `YoungTableau_B` is defined in a namespace `ns_young_tableau_B`, however the implementation of `MakeCellYT` is defined in a namespace `ns_young_tableau_i_B`. They should be in the same namespace. Secondly since `MakeCellYT` is a member function its implementation should be defined as

```
template<typename T>
ns_young_tableau_A::YoungTableau_A::Cell_T YoungTableau_B::MakeCellYT(T i, T j)
```

(note the addition of `YoungTableau_B::`)

Once that's fixed you'll encounter an issue where you've called this function with a template parameter `int` so the line

```
T Result = {i,j};
```

is attempting to assign an initializer list to an integer which is an error. Possibly you meant `Cell_T Result = {i,j};`

In general I'm not sure you really need to split the implementation out into seperate files, these sorts of errors would be easier to diagnose if you just defined and implemented the class in a single header.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @ChrisD. Indeed I don't have to split the implementation out into separate headers. I did it as exercise to study how  references are connected in different headers :). I'll try to do as you said. Would that even be possible edit the code to keep different namespaces as I did?

Comment: You need to define the function in the same namespace that you declared it in. If you want to keep the definition of `MakeCellYT` in the namespace it's currently in then you can write it as `::ns_young_tableau_B::YoungTableau_B::MakeCellYT`

Comment: I changed header_i_.hpp files using the same namespace. It works :) Thank you very much :)

Comment: Perfect @ChrisD. Thank you very much :)

Comment: I need your help for another issue that I found in the code. The function YOUNG_TABLEAU.ExtractMinYT(Tableau) is correctly called from Main.cpp. I defined and initialized a couple of Cell_T variables on the top of the function called CurYT2 and Next2. During the debugging I discovered that these variables aren't created: the debugger jumps directly to  "int MinYT = 0;" 
from "ns_young_tableau_A::YoungTableau_A::Cell_T CurYT2;". Both the variables don't appear among the local variables and I don't know which is the mistake. Thank you in advance for any suggestions :)

Comment: Without seeing the code I can only speculate, but two things that could cause these are either the source is out-of-sync with the binary being debugged, or alternatively you aren't doing anything else with these variables so the compiler has just optimized them out.

Comment: How can happen that the source is out-of-sync? It's strange. I have initialized them and they should appear among the locals. I'd pass you a screenshot of the execution, but I don't have enough privileges yet :(